# Where to store credentials?

Tags: node.js, security, amazon-s3, file-upload

I'm building an app that includes an image uploading feature and I have decided to use AWS S3 as a file storing service. In order to upload an image to AWS s3, you need to provide the API with credentials to the service. And to keep these credentials secure, I've decided to store them in my own server, and only provide them to the clients when they need to upload an Image.

**Following is my procedure of uploading images:**

1. The client chooses images from the camera roll and clicks upload button
2. The app makes request to **my own server** and gets response with access-keys to the image hosting service (AWS s3)
3. The client now has access to upload the images to AWS s3. Credentials is deleted from the client after upload is done.

**My questions are:**

1. Is it secure to do it that way? - and is there a better way of handling this problem?
2. Where should I store the credentials in my server to keep them secure? I mean should I store them in a file, in database, in code?

*I use graphql/expressjs as backend and react native as frontend.

Comment: I googled "client upload to aws" and the first result was http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingHTTPPOST.html - I think that's what you want to use

Comment: Thanx!. Yes, the signed url method looks very secure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*1) Is it secure to do it that way? -and are there a better way of handling theproblem ?*

-- NO its not secure, you should generate signed url and send it to your client, and client will directly make post to the s3 using that signed url.
(http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingHTTPPOST.html)

2) where should i store the credentials in my server to keep them secure? I mean should i store them in a file, in database, in code?

-- Always store the credentials in aws parameter store or hashicorp vault, and when the app starts, make a call to it and get the credentials.

(https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/systems-manager/parameter-store/)

(https://www.vaultproject.io/)

Comment: Thank you very much! That is very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

However, as far as location goes, for most of the cases you're going to encounter (and I honestly can't think of any counter-examples) storing the representation of a password in the database is the proper thing to do. By representation I mean that you want to hash the password using a salt (which should be different for every user) and a secure 1-way algorithm and store that, throwing away the original password. Then, when you want to verify a password, you hash the value (using the same hashing algorithm and salt) and compare it to the hashed value in the database.

How to best store user information and user login and password
Best practices for storing database passwords
Salting Your Password: Best Practices?
Is it ever ok to store password in plain text in a php variable or php constant?
To clarify a bit further on the salting bit, the danger with simply hashing a password and storing that is that if a trespasser gets a hold of your database, they can still use what are known as rainbow tables to be able to "decrypt" the password (at least those that show up in the rainbow table). To get around this, developers add a salt to passwords which, when properly done, makes rainbow attacks simply infeasible to do. Do note that a common misconception is to simply add the same unique and long string to all passwords; while this is not horrible, it is best to add unique salts to every password. Read for salt more.

salt = http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)

Comment: Thank you for the anser, Ankit.
The problem is that i want to upload the images directly from the client to reduce the on-server work. So the credentials has to be sent from the client to the aws s3 server with no encryption.

Comment: Ok, so then check if AWS s3 server provide you something to store your credentials securely. I am sure they had something for you. Good Day!

Comment: Did you find anything in AWS s3?

Comment: Yes, see @Madhan S's answer.